# Anchor test case shows pending

Tags: anchor, anchor-test

I get 1 pending test case (0 passing, 0 failed) when running anchor test on the following code:

```
  const [trader, nftMint] = Array.from({ length: 2 }, () => Keypair.generate());
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());
  const provider = anchor.getProvider();
  const connection = provider.connection;
  it("Create trader account"), async () => {
    let tx = new Transaction();
    const lamports = await getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint(connection);

    tx.instructions = [
      SystemProgram.createAccount({
        fromPubkey: provider.publicKey,
        newAccountPubkey: trader.publicKey,
        lamports,
        space: 0,
        programId: SystemProgram.programId
      }),
      SystemProgram.transfer({
        fromPubkey: provider.publicKey,
        toPubkey: trader.publicKey,
        lamports: 0.02 * 1e9
      })
    ]
    await provider.sendAndConfirm(tx, [trader]).then(log);
    assert.ok((await connection.getBalance(trader.publicKey)) == 0.02 * 1e9);
  }
```

I can tell that this is probably because the transaction is not finalizing, but I'm unsure why this is happening. I'm running on localnet as well. Anchor 0.29, solana 1.18.1